# Kohana 3 form select validation

Tags: kohana

Hay all, 
I am trying to validate a select in kohana 3.0 and I am using the necessary rules. However the validation does no "kick in" when the user does not make a selection.

```
<select id="discipline" name="discipline" >
<option value="0"> -- Select One -- </option>
<option value="-2">Information Technology and Engineering</option>
<option value="4">Business and Training Seminars</option>
</select>
```

That was my select, now i have applied these rules to the post array before i check for validation errors.

```
$post = Validate::factory($_POST)
                ->rule('discipline', 'not_empty')
                ->rule('discipline', 'numeric');
```

When I submit the form without making a selection, the form submits and the rules should stop it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your still putting a value for the first one, as 0. Leave the value as value="". 0 is numeric and considered not empty.

Comment: or remove `value` attribute from the first option

Comment: If you remove value, then the value will become  -- Select One --  Which will not work

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace 0 with blank string
2. Add `->rule('discipline', 'in_array', array(array(-2, 4)));` to check that selected discipline is within valid collection.

Answer (score 0):

string empty first option

```
<select name="fruit" required>
  <option value="">select fruit</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
```

then some css may help

```
form:invalid button[type="submit"], form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}
```